# Get all images loaded into a dynamic text box in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was able to smooth the loaded, rotated images in my textbox as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624754/enable-smoothing-on-imported-rotated-image-in-dynamic-text-box-in-flash-as3). That solution requires that I know the id of the images that are coming in. Is there a way to generalize and get a list of all the images coming in?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to parse out the  ids with a regular expression ?

Comment: hmm, yeah, that will work, assuming the images all have ids in the source. I can probably enforce that, but what if they don't?

Comment: Interesting, you could actually add the id tags to the string representing the HTML before applying it to the textfield. That way you would always be aware of the ids and the exact number. Same method of course (replace + regexp)